# Why is Unicode combining character order different between IDEA and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, intellij-idea, unicode

In Java, I am generating a string with letters `A` and `B` with a [COMBINING OVERLINE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0305/index.htm) U+0305 character in between.

```
@Test
public void test() {
  System.out.println("A\u0305B");
}
```

I get this in IDEA:

[image]

But if I copy to here, it will become `A̅B`.

---

This one is from the Chrome console:

[image]

I was confused by the [combining character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)'s combining order. Which one is correct?

I was writing [this](https://wenerme.github.io/kori/qm) in Kotlin and compiling to JavaScript to run in the browser. Debugging in IDEA is correct, but the browser shows a different answer.

Comment: I go the horizontal stroke on the A in both IntelliJ and Chrome though...

Comment: FWIW, on my system Idea has problems with some fonts, e.g. when Menlo is used as a console font, it displays `A̅` as `A‾` . This is a display issue only, the string is correct per se. I guess it would be helpful to report that to JetBrains.

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA. Specify the OS and font you are using for the editor.

Comment: I see the line over the B (using Firefox on Linux).

Comment: @boann: did you simply load a document containing the character sequence, or tried something along "document.write"? Because those correctly put the overline on "A" on my Firefox. Or did you do it via kotlin/other stuff transpiling to Javascript?

Comment: @jsbueno I was just looking at what I see on this page in the question, although now I realize it depends on the font. In this comment box, I see A̅B has the line over the A, but in the question and question edit box, it's over the B, but in the question it moves to the A if I remove the backticks/monospace. I copied it into a Google Search, and it's over the A, including in the title bar and URL bar. So I guess it's just the monospace font that's problematic. I have a bunch of Windows Vista fonts installed; maybe that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one is to believe Wikipedia and refraining from jumping into the dense Unicode Consortium authoritative PDF jungle, the text related to this is "[In Unicode, diacritics are always added after the main character (in contrast to some older combining character sets such as ANSEL), so it is possible to add several diacritics to the same character, although as of 2010, few applications support correct rendering of such combinations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)" (Maybe I should edit the page at that point to add the "citation needed", though).

Anyway, in both GTK+, SDL and both Browsers in my system, Overline is drawn on the preceeding character. My Qt apps do not support this character, but all its siblings diacriticals - including "\u0304" and "\u0306",  are drawn on the preceding character. And unlike overline, these are used in "real world" text in latin languages, which would be rendered in an absurdly incorrect way with the diactricals shifted.

From these points, I think it is clear that the subsystems rendering the sign on the following letter are buggy. Moreover as we can see from the comments, the problem might lie just on the fonts in use - buggy fonts are better than buggy IDE.